# escape character is not working when sending as argument to onclick function

Tags: javascript

I am creating a button dynamically through javascript and trying to pass a string as argument to the onclick function as below.

```
let control = '<li class="buttons-container">';
control += `<button class="gray-button" onclick="diagBtnClick('${yesStepIntent}', '${yesBtnLbl}')">${yesBtnLbl}</button>`;
```

In the above code, I am passing 2 arguments to onclick function. yesBtnLbl value is coming from server. If it doesn't contain any single quote character with in a string, it is working fine. For example, **yesBtnLbl = 'I will'** is working fine. But **yesBtnLbl = "I'll"** is not working. Even I tried with **yesBtnLbl = "I'll"** and also yesBtnLbl = 'I'll'; which is also not working. Every time it is throwing error **'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'** when I tried to hit the button if the string contains single quote character within the string.

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In instances like this you can try changing your quotes around;

```
control += "<button class='gray-button' onclick='diagBtnClick("${yesStepIntent}", "${yesBtnLbl}")'>"${yesBtnLbl}"</button>";
```

But this will break if you use `"` in your variable.

EDIT: Or you can try;

```
control += `<button class='gray-button' onclick='diagBtnClick("${yesStepIntent}", "${yesBtnLbl}")'>${yesBtnLbl}</button>`;
```

Comment: Just now I tried and it is working. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yeah you can essentially use ``'`` or ``"`` in your code, as long as it's consistent on the line you're using it (if this makes sense).